# How can I add list to screen with menu in java-me

Tags: list, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have a problem about java-me list. I can create a list and add it to screen but I couldn't add any menu bottom of the screen like 'Back'.

I used this code:

```
String[] degerler = {"StringItem", "TextField", "DateField","ImageItem", "Gauge", "ChoiceGroup","List", "Alert", "Sounds"};

favlistelement = new List("Reservation type", List.IMPLICIT,degerler, null);
```

and I added it to screen with this code:

```
disp.setCurrent(favlistelement );
```

In fact I have a form variable called `favoritesscreen,` I want to add the list to this screen with menu like 'Back'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way

```
    backfavorites = new Command("Back",Command.BACK,0);

    favlistelement = new List("Favorites:", List.IMPLICIT);
    favlistelement.append("Incoming 1", null);
    favlistelement.append("Incoming 2", null);    
    favlistelement.append("Incoming 3", null);

    favlistelement.addCommand(backfavorites);
    favlistelement.setCommandListener(this);
```

I was trying to add listeners, command to my Form variable but I tried to add these to my list element variable thus it was solved.

To show in screen:

```
disp.setCurrent(favlistelement);
```